# Should Ed25519 verification multiply by the cofactor?

Tags: signature, ed25519

The standardization document for Ed25519, [RFC 8032](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032#section-5.1.7), says the following method should be used for verifying Ed25519 signatures:

> 3. Check the group equation $[8][S]B = [8]R + [8][k]A'$.  It's sufficient, but not required, to instead check $[S]B = R + [k]A'$.

Does that mean that code doing verification should point-multiply both sides by $8 = 2^c$ for cofactor $c$ or should they not?  The document and [various](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55656/should-ed25519-signature-verification-check-the-order-and-canonicity-of-its-inpu) [questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75900/order-of-subgroups-formed-by-elliptic-curves-with-a-cofactor) here on CryptoExchange don't really answer whether I as implementer should multiply both sides by $8$ when implementing the standard.

I understand what the number $8$ is; the order of the Ed25519 cyclic group is $8\ell$ for a 253-bit prime $\ell$, and $|B| = \ell$.  So $B$ is pre-multiplied by $8$ to make it part of the $\ell$-order subgroup.

Comment: The key point is the [legimate user don't choose such points](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55643/18298)..

Comment: Do we assume the signer as an illegitimate user? What would happen if you see that they use small order? You can control, but not necessary.

Comment: The public key is trusted, so this would matter only for bad signatures against that public key.  Also, that signatures wouldn't be unique (add some $Q$ of order ${2,4,8}$ to $R$ and you get another distinct signature for the same data, without needing to be the original signer. @kelalaka

Comment: yes. 5.1.5 mentions legitimate users. In any case, it is not computing-intensive, you can still check for a possible malicious user.