# Is libsodium's Key Exchange system secure?

Tags: keys, key-exchange, authenticated-encryption

I'm building a project using libsodium's AEAD + Key Exchange system and want to write a proof justifying the security of the project. I am wondering if I can find a source detailing the exact security definition libsodium's Key Exchange system satisfies.

I know the textbook definition of IND-CCA2 and that AEAD satisfies it, but I'm not sure how to formalize the "combined" security of AEAD using a secret key generated from a Key Exchange algorithm.

More specifically, I'm interested in a proof of the non-existence of a "backdoor" public key that, when exchanged with a private key and then used in encryption, would leak information about that private key.

Comment: The answer to the question of 'is it secure?' is yes assuming you use `crypto_kx` and not just `crypto_scalarmult` or `crypto_box`, which don't include the public keys for shared secret/key derivation. This can be a [vulnerability](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-7), which doesn't seem to be very well known.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a formal security definition on for which adversary is it secure? I'm mostly interested in the case of a very active adversary that can observe existing public keys and do key exchange with honest users.

Comment: I have added some clarification about the problem.

Comment: There are [weak public keys](https://vnhacker.blogspot.com/2015/09/why-not-validating-curve25519-public.html) for X25519, but libsodium [rejects](https://doc.libsodium.org/internals#security-first) them. That affects shared secrets though, not leaking someone's private key, which shouldn't be possible. However, you [can](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/170) leak an Ed25519 private key when signing a message with the correct public key and then an incorrect public key.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply! Is there, to your knowledge, a formal proof justifying the "shouldn't be possible"?

Comment: Perhaps read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55661). There's probably something in the Curve25519 paper.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments!