# Curve25519/Montgomery curves points with order 8

Tags: elliptic-curves

I found [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/curve25519-weak-points-for-contributory-behaviour) about Curve25519. It states, that there are only 5 points with a very low order. With [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.559.7774&rep=rep1&type=pdf) I was able to understand, how the points with order 2 and 4 were computed. My question is: How to compute the points with order 8?

Comment: Related [Invalid curve attack: finding low order points](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71065/18298) or even dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curve25519 has order $8\cdot q$, and we want a point of order $8$. This is the laziest solution I can think of:

1. Generate a random point $P$ on the curve;
2. Compute $Q = [q]P$. This point has order $1$, $2$, $4$ or $8$.
3. If $Q$ is not of order $8$, go back to step 1.

A sample code to see the points we get:

```
E = EllipticCurve(GF(2^255-19),[0,486662,0,1,0])
for i in range(20):
    P = E.random_element()
    Q = P.__mul__(2^252 + 0x14def9dea2f79cd65812631a5cf5d3ed)
    print (Q.order(), Q)
```

Expect a few attemps until a point of order $8$ is found.

---

Another way to do this is to use [division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials).

Just giving the general idea about them. There is a series of polynomials whose roots are related to torsion points. Basically, the points $P$ such that $[n]P = \infty$ have their $x$-coordinate as roots of a polynomial.

However, those roots can be over an extension field, so they do not correspond exactly to points on the elliptic curve over the base field.

Using SageMath, we can find the $8$-torsion points of Curve25519:

```
sage: p = 2^255 - 19                                                                                  
sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,486662,0,1,0])                                                      
sage: E.division_polynomial(8).roots(multiplicities=False)                                            
[0,
 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819948,
 39382357235489614581723060781553021112529911719440698176882885853963445705823,
 325606250916557431795983626356110631294008115727848805560023387167927233504,
 1]
```

There is the point $(0,0)$ of order $2$, the next root corresponds to two points of order $4$ on Curve25519 over $\mathbf F_{p^2}$, the next two roots to four points of order $8$, and the last one to two points of order $4$.

Comment: This is a pretty good idea and it works. Because I did not know this is possible, there is some math I don't quite know/understand. Can you shortly state, why this is possible?

Comment: It has nothing to do with elliptic curves, just only group theory. If you have an element $g$ of order $p_1p_2$ in a group, then $h = g^{p_2}$ is an element of order $p_1$ (since $h^{p_1}=g^{p_1p_2}=1$. On Curve25519, a random point is likely to have $q$ as a factor in its order, so by multiplying by $q$, the order of the resulting point has only a few possible values, which is a divisor of the curve cofactor.

Comment: A quick way to find the points of $8$-torsion in Sage is `E.torsion_polynomial(8).roots(multiplicities=False)`. It will give the $x$-coordinate of the points. One of them corresponds to points on the curve over $\mathbf F_{p^2}$, but all the others adding the infinity point make the count to $8$.

Comment: Uhm something is weird. I can create this list of points with a low order, but the second points, which should have $x = -1$ can not be created. I did this using $F_p$ but not $F_{p^2}$. So why does this list with $E$ over $F_p$ contains $x = -1$?

Comment: $(-1) + 486662\cdot (-1)^2 + (-1)$ is not a square so there is no point $(-1, y)$ on Curve25519.

Comment: @corpsfini Yes I did the math, too. But what confuses me is: The code you provided produces a list with $x=-1$ included. But it is not on $E$ over $F_p$.

Comment: @kelalaka I started to complete the answer. Feel free to clean the comments.