# Calculate a base point on the twist of secp192k1 with maximal order

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I want to calculate a base point on the twist of secp192k1 with maximal order.

```
'secp192k1': _ECData(
    p=2**192 - 2**32 - 2**12 - 2**8 - 2**7 - 2**6 - 2**3 - 1, 
    a=0, b=3,
    Gx=0xDB4FF10EC057E9AE26B07D0280B7F4341DA5D1B1EAE06C7D, 
   Gy=0x9B2F2F6D9C5628A7844163D015BE86344082AA88D95E2F9D,


 n=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE26F2FC170F69466A74DEFD8D
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111273/discussion-on-question-by-maximus-calculate-a-base-point-on-the-twist-of-secp192).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\beta$ a non-square element in $\mathbf{F}_p$, then the elliptic curve defined by $\beta y^2 = x^3 + 3$ is a quadratic twist of `secp192k1` whose equation is $y^2 = x^3 + 3$.

It means that if $x_0^3 + 3$ is a square, there exists $y_0 \in \mathbf{F}_p$ that is a square root of $x_0^3 + 3$, so $(x_0, y_0)$ belongs to `secp192k1`, and on the other hand if $x_0^3 + 3$ is **not** a square, there exists $y_0$ such that $\beta y_0^2 = x_0^3 + 3$, so $(x_0, y_0)$ lies on the quadratic twist instead. Here, we can take $\beta = -1$ since it is not a square in the finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$.

There is a relation between the cardinality (number of points) with the quadratic twist. The cardinality of `secp192k1` is a prime number $n$, that can be rewritten as
$$
n = p + 1 - t,
$$
where the value $t$ is called the *trace of Frobenius*. Then it is easy to compute the cardinality $n'$ of the quadratic twist:
$$
\begin{align}
n' & = p + 1 + t, \\
& = 3 \cdot 373 \cdot 56383 \cdot 619124299 \cdot 160695254510139039862526647837522958722153.
\end{align}
$$
Write $n'= h\cdot q$ where $q$ is the largest prime in the decomposition. The goal is to find a point of order $q$ on the twist. Let's use `SageMath` for the computation, but unfortunately it does not handle elliptic curves with an equation of the form $-y^2 = x^3 + 3$. That's not a problem, a simple change of variable will do the trick: let $x'=-x$, and the equation becomes $-y^2 = -x'^3 + 3$, and by multiplying each side by $-1$ we get $y^2 = x'^3 - 3$.

We can make some check that all is good:

```
p = 2**192 - 2**32 - 2**12 - 2**8 - 2**7 - 2**6 - 2**3 - 1
E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0, 3])
n = E.cardinality()
print(n.is_prime())
t = p + 1 - n
Et = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0, -3])
nn = Et.cardinality()
print(nn == p + 1 + t)
print(Et.is_quadratic_twist(E))
```

The last command returns a nonzero value if the two curves are indeed a quadratic twist of each other.

To find a point whose order is the largest prime $q$, we can run something similar as in [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/82079/69015).

1. Generate a random point on the twist;
2. Compute $Q = [h]P$;
3. If $Q \neq \mathcal{O}$, then $Q$ is a point of order $q$.

```
h = 39062147507228523
q = 160695254510139039862526647837522958722153
while True:
    P = Et.random_element()
    Q = h*P
    if Q != Et(0):
        break
print(Q)
print(Q.order() == q)
```

Comment: The relation of the cardinality of of a Curve and it's quadratic twist over a finite field can be better explained as either the $y$ is a quadratic residue or a non-quadratic residue. So the curve and the twist contains exactly two points $(x,y_i)$ for $x\in F_p$. So in total, it makes $2q+2$ with the point of infinity counted twice. Now we can use the trace of the Frobenius.