# What is a formula of a twist?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

With the curve secp256k1, the order of the twist is 3×197×1559×96769×146849×2587814237219×375925338294461779×101009178936527559588563023359

But I can't understand what is formula of this twist(twist is not standart).

Article were "formulated" this twist - [https://www.di.ens.fr/~fouque/pub/fdtc08.pdf](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Efouque/pub/fdtc08.pdf)

Comment: You can use this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82154/18298)